# Removing rows in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a file that with about 24 columns and many rows like this:

```
| ID| Pos| S1 | S2| S3| S4|  ...S24
|---|----|----|---|---|---|
| A | 22 | .  | 1 | 0 | . |
| B | 21 | 1  | 0 | . |1  |
| C | 50 | 0  | . | . |.  |
| D | 11 | .  | 1 | . |.  |
```

I would like to remove all rows where the samples(from S1 - S24) have only "." and "0" and all rows where the samples have only "." and "1" such that like in the dummy table above , rows C and D would be removed and A and B retained.

I tried using rowsums in R unsuccesfully;

```
NEW_FILE <- file[rowSums(file == "." & file == "1") < 24, ]
```

I appreciate any suggestions in R or otherwise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Vectorized` options for `filter`ing.  Below, there are <strike>three</strike> four options that does this

**1)** Using  `str_c` and `reduce`.   We `select` the columns with names that `starts_with` 'S', use `reduce` (from `purrr`) to concat as a single string (with `str_c`), then use `str_detect` to check whether there are only one or more 0 and `.` (`[0.]+`)  from the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string or (`|`) only one or more 1 and `.`.  Negate (`!`) the logical expression and keep the rest of the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
file %>% 
     filter(!str_detect(reduce(select(cur_data(), starts_with('S')), 
        str_c, sep=""), '^([0.]+|[1.]+)$'))
 #  ID Pos S1 S2 S3 S4
 #1  A  22  .  1  0  .
 #2  B  21  1  0  .  1
```

---

**2)** Another option is `if_all` to `filter` only rows that have element `.` and `0` from the 'S' columns, use `setdiff` with the original data to get the remaining rows, apply a second `if_all` to generate a logical expressionn where rows have only `.` and `1`, negate (`!`) to return the rest of the rows

```
file %>% 
  filter(if_all(starts_with('S'), ~ . %in% c('.', 0))) %>% 
  setdiff(file, .) %>%
  filter(!if_all(starts_with('S'), ~ . %in% c('.', 1)))
#  ID Pos S1 S2 S3 S4
#1  A  22  .  1  0  .
#2  B  21  1  0  .  1
```

---

**3)** We could avoid the `setdiff` step by creating a temporary logical column ('i1') after the first `if_all` and use that in the `filter` with next `if_all`

```
file %>%
   mutate(i1 = if_all(starts_with('S'), ~ . %in% c('.', 0))) %>% 
   filter(!(i1 | if_all(starts_with('S'), ~ . %in% c('.', 1)))) %>% 
   select(-i1)
#  ID Pos S1 S2 S3 S4
#1  A  22  .  1  0  .
#2  B  21  1  0  .  1
```

**4)** Or we can use `rowSums` to create compound logical expressions which can be joined together with `&`

```
file %>%
   filter(rowSums(select(cur_data(), starts_with('S')) == '1') > 0 &
          rowSums(select(cur_data(), starts_with('S')) == '0') > 0)
#  ID Pos S1 S2 S3 S4
#1  A  22  .  1  0  .
#2  B  21  1  0  .  1
```

#### data

```
file <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Pos = c(22L, 21L, 
50L, 11L), S1 = c(".", "1", "0", "."), S2 = c("1", "0", ".", 
"1"), S3 = c("0", ".", ".", "."), S4 = c(".", "1", ".", ".")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thanks a lot. Ive learned much from the different options you demostrated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
file %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(sum(!(c_across(-c(ID,Pos)) %in% c(".","0"))) > 0 &
         sum(!(c_across(-c(ID,Pos)) %in% c(".","1"))) > 0)
#  ID      Pos S1    S2    S3    S4   
#  <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 A        22 .     1     0     .    
#2 B        21 1     0     .     1
```

We can use the `rowwise` dplyr verb to work on each row. Then `c_across` to work on only the `S` columns. We can check if all are in `c(".","0")` and then repeat the process for `c(".","1")`. We filter (ie keep) rows where both conditions are `TRUE`.

If there are other non-"S" columns, you might use `c_across(starts_with("S"))` instead.

Data:

```
file <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Pos = c(22L, 21L, 
50L, 11L), S1 = c(".", "1", "0", "."), S2 = c("1", "0", ".", 
"1"), S3 = c("0", ".", ".", "."), S4 = c(".", "1", ".", ".")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your suggestion. I have tried it and it didnt work as I want it to. I would like to only keep rows that have all ".", "1" and "0" across the samples. So I want to remove the rows with either only "." and "0", as well as rows with "." and "1" only.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misunderstood your question, my edit should take care of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `base R` solution with regex:

```
file[-which(grepl("^[0.]+$|^[1.]+$", apply(file[,-1], 1, paste, collapse = ""))),]
  ID S1 S2 S3 S4
1  A  .  1  0  .
2  B  1  0  .  1
```

Here, we first collapse the rows into strings with `apply`and `paste`and then we subset `file` on those rows `which` do **not** match the pattern that they either **only** contain `.` and `1` OR `.` and `0`from start `^` to end `$`

If you prefer a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
file %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(string = paste(c_across(starts_with('S')),collapse = "")) %>%
  filter(!grepl("^[0.]+$|^[1.]+$", string)) %>%
  select(-string)
```

Data:

```
file <- data.frame(
  ID = LETTERS[1:4],
  S1 = c(".", "1", "0", "."),
  S2 = c("1", "0", ".", "1"),
  S3 = c("0", ".", ".", "."),
  S4 = c(".", "1", ".", ".")
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `.` can be found in every row, this also can be another solution. However, if that's not the case I need to make some modifications:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

file %>%
  mutate(Con = pmap_lgl(file %>% 
                          select(starts_with("S")), ~ all(any(str_detect(c(...), "1")),
                          any(str_detect(c(...), "0"))))) %>%
  filter(Con) %>%
  select(-Con)

  ID Pos S1 S2 S3 S4
1  A  22  .  1  0  .
2  B  21  1  0  .  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this base R option using `subset` + `apply` + `%in%` could help (thank [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67451847/12158757) for the data)

```
> subset(file, apply(file, 1, function(x) all(c("0", "1", ".") %in% x) | sum(x == ".") + 2 == length(x)))
  ID Pos S1 S2 S3 S4
1  A  22  .  1  0  .
2  B  21  1  0  .  1
```